# Excel Substring

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substring

I'm trying to substring a date range,

> Ex. 1/17/16-1/18/17 in Cell A1 to 
>   1/17/16 in cell B1 and 1/18/17 to Cell B2

I have:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("-",A1)-1) Expecting 1/17/16
=RIGHT(A1, FIND("-",A1)+1) Expecting 1/18/17
```

But I get:

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("-",A1)-1) results 1/17/16
=RIGHT(A1, FIND("-",A1)+1) Results 6-1/18/17
```

But for certain date ranges,

> 1/1/17-12/31/19 which is in A2

I get 1/1/17 in B2 and 12/31/19 in C2
The code is exactly same, except for the cell A2...

Can someone explain why this is happening?
In certain cases, my RIGHT brings back results like

> 17-5/28/17

as well...

Thanks in advance

Comment: =RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1))`

Second parameter is `[num_chars]`, so correct methodology is subtract LENGTH from POSITION OF '-'

What you're doing is providing the POSITION as a length.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Right` can be painstaking. I prefer using `Mid` instead.

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("-",A1)-1)
=MID(A1, (FIND("-",A1) +1), LEN(A1)-1)
=LEFT(A2, FIND("-",A2)-1)
=MID(A2, (FIND("-",A2) +1), LEN(A2)-1)
```